# how to retrieve users data from firebase auth in react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have manually imported JSON file for the database with the following users:

```js
{
  "users": {
    "Naseebullah": {
      "name": "Naseebullah Ahmadi",
      "gender": "Male",
      "type": "Patient",
      "Doctors": ["Ernest"],
      "age": "20",
      "DOB": "02/06/1997",
      "address": "122 Atherstone Court",
      "contactNumber": "07473693312",
      "emailAddress": "Naseebullah@kcl.ac.uk",
      "profilePicture": "../Images/profile.jpg",
      "ECG": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000050048828125, 0.0000137939453125],
      "HeartSound": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000050048828125, 0.0000137939453125]
    },

    "Ernest": {
      "name": "Ernest Kamavuako",
      "gender": "Male",
      "type": "Doctor",
      "Patients": ["Naseebullah"],
      "age": "30",
      "DOB": "20/12/1970",
      "address": "122 Harrow Street",
      "contactNumber": "07473033312",
      "emailAddress": "Ernest@kcl.ac.uk",
      "profilePicture": "../Images/profile.jpg",
      "ECG": [""],
      "HeartSound": [""]
    }
  }
}
```

and I have manually created two users for authentication:
[image]

The issue is when I log in as "Naseebullah" (naseebullah@kcl.ac.uk), I don't receive his details:

```js
"Naseebullah": {
  "name": "Naseebullah Ahmadi",
  "gender": "Male",
  "type": "Patient",
  "Doctors": ["Ernest"],
  "age": "20",
  "DOB": "02/06/1997",
  "address": "122 Atherstone Court",
  "contactNumber": "07473693312",
  "emailAddress": "Naseebullah@kcl.ac.uk",
  "profilePicture": "../Images/profile.jpg",
  "ECG": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000050048828125, 0.0000137939453125],
  "HeartSound": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0000050048828125, 0.0000137939453125]
},
```

In other words, I don't get his name, gender and so on...

This is where I authenticate:

```js
const onLogin = creds => {
  const { email, password } = creds;
  //console.log("props123 ", values, nav);
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => {
    console.log("user: ", user);
    /*
     * User is logged in
     *
     * */
  }).catch(err => {
    const { code,message } = err;
    console.log("not loggedin, ", message);
  });
};
```

How can I retrieve the user's details from the database when the user is authenticated with email and password?

Comment: it looks like `email` is common in your auth and database. so first get the email from auth and then query users who has the specific email and display the data.

Comment: Are you implying that we make the email as a unique key for classifying individuals? I think that's unsafe, No? @Hareesh

Comment: Is there a better and alternative way?

Comment: that is the only way i can think you can reach to current user right now.

Answer (score 1):

The authentication subsystem, `firebase.auth()` is not where to store user profile information.  `firebase.auth()` will create a `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` unique identifier for each user and may provide a few details such as an email address, photoURL, etc.

Create a `users` collection and store each users profile data such as age in a document whos identifier is the `firebase.auth()` uid.

Use `.onAuthStateChanged` to detect user sign in state and to subscribe to (get) the users profile data from the data store.

Answer (score 0):

With your current database structure you can fetch the user data in your `onLogin` method by doing:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref('users')
  .orderByChild('emailAddress')
  .equalTo(email)
  .once('value', snap => console.log(snap.val()));
```

To get the current user data.

However you should not be using the users' first names as keys in the `users` node, what will happen when you have two users named Ernest? It will break (you will delete the first Ernest user). Consider instead using the auth uid as the key, which is guaranteed to be unique and bound the user.

Comment: Well said indeed. I had struggled how to set up the JSON structure so that the keys can be used as primary form of identity. I'll update you guys in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the firebase website:

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
   console.log("user: ", user);
   // User is signed in.
  } else {
   // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users